# Can setTimeout() trigger a JSF form validation?

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf

I have created a JSF form with some input text fields. Also, I have added a JavaScript function in the JSF that is called from the bean. The work that the function does is to show a component and after some seconds it should hide it. Here are the function located in the jsf and the component:

```
function func() {
    var comp = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId("abc");
    comp.setVisible(true);
    setTimeout(function(){
      comp.setVisible(false);
    }, 5000);
}

<af:outputText value="Some EL text" id="abc" visible="false"/>
```

This is the backing bean code that calls the function:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExtendedRenderKitService erks =
    Service.getRenderKitService(context, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);

erks.addScript(context, "func();");
```

The problem is that when the time (5000ms in this case) is over, the component hides, the form validation is triggered and the data which is entered during the time the component is shown is reset. I don`t want the data to be reset. Any ideas why it happens in this way and how I can resolve it? Is the problem connected with the setTimeout() function or it is an ADF specific matter?

Comment: The data being reset should happen due to an ADF trigger event that refresh the composant. Could you edit your question to show us the jsf component and the bean function that call the js ?

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: Add the immediate="true" property to the button that call the java bean function. this will avoid triggering the lifecycle refresh